# How to get the filepath to save and load the user preferences in Surface SDK?

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I am developing an app for Microsoft Surface using Surface SDK.
But not sure where should I save the user preferences such as login information(password or token).
Also, how to determine the file path to save the profile image?

Comment: Have you checked out any of the [MSDN Surface Samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727811.aspx) sounds like a good place to start.. if  that's not enough try a google search

Comment: There is no related sample, already checked.

Comment: YouTube has some video tutorials sorry sounds like you're gonna have to do some more digging unless someone on here has actually coded using the SDK try this search `microsoft surface development tutorial`

Comment: Thank you, but I can't even find the related sample.